# firefox where is the 3d element inspector button?

Tags: javascript, firefox, 3d

I saw someone using Firefox's developer console/tools and they brought up a 3D view of their page.  I figured I'd do that too ... so I go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View to learn how to get the 3D view.

The doc says, "When you click on the 3D view button, the page goes into 3D view mode." OK great but where the heck is the 3D view button?

Comment: [The button must be enabled for it to appear](http://superuser.com/questions/774846/does-firefox-30-still-have-the-3d-dom-viewer).

Comment: Thanks user29*. How does one enable it?

Comment: My comment was a link.